# Wrong IP assigned to raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-wheezy, static-ip

Hello I have a strange problem. I assigned static IP to my raspberry - 10.10.10.120 (I did the same thing on my Mikrotik router). It was working perfectly until today, when I couldn't connect to PI remotely. Finally I saw that my router assigned another IP - 10.10.10.56, and I have access via that IP. Even if I delete assigned IP from router, and reboot the PI, router will assing the same IP.

Luckily I'm just testing my project for now, but this can't happen again later. Is this router or PI problem? I'm using wheezy OS.

Comment: I'll leave the answer to people who know wheezy better, but for starters: it is imho not a good idea to set up a static IP in two places (on the Pi **and** the router). If you set a static IP on the Pi, have it outside the router's IP range used for dhcp. If you set up the IP on the router, you would not need a static setting on the Pi, but use the dhcp client.

Comment: 10.10.10.120 is out of my dhcp pool though. And it doesn't matter if I make it static on router or not. I have just deleted the static entry on router and it makes no difference, 10.10.10.56 is assigned.

Comment: Sounds to me like conflicting network configuration on the Pi (on Arch you can have such issues when using netctl and networkd at the same time, don't ask why anyone would do that ;) ) Are you sure that the Pi, for whatever reason, is not also running a network config with dhcp client?

Comment: It shouldn't, I have just changed the etc/network/interfaces file, and there is the line that says: iface eth0 inet static. Its strange that the other raspberry (webserver with 10.10.10.110 IP) is working as intended.

Comment: Unless you post your configuration files (and exactly which version of Raspbian you are running). Al you can get is idle speculation.